# List view Item data insert to a List<> in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My list view ItemTemplate is as follows

```
<a href='<%# getpath(Eval("IMAGE_PATH")) %>' title='<%# Eval("IMAGE_DESCRIPTION") %>'>
   <asp:Image ID="capty" CssClass="capty" runat="server" 
       AlternateText='<%# Eval("IMAGE_DESCRIPTION") %>' 
       ImageUrl='<%# retriveurl(Eval("IMAGE_PATH")) %>' 
       Height="100px" Width="150px">
   </asp:Image>
</a>
```

my codebehind source is

```
int count=ListView1.Items.Count;
    List<ImageGallery> _list = new List<ImageGallery>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ImageGallery ob = new ImageGallery();
        ob.ImageName = ??
        ob.Description = ??
        _list.Add(ob);
    }
```

now i want to insert the Eval("IMAGE_DESCRIPTION") data to a ob.Description and ob.ImageName=Eval("IMAGE_ID") .How to do this?

```
List<ImageGallery> _list = new List<ImageGallery>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count; i++) 
{ 
    ImageGallery ob = new ImageGallery(); 
    ob.ImageName = ""; 
    ob.Description = " "; 
    _list.Add(ob); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?  What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I try to describe it.Can I understand u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to get the image.  You pass it the ID of the control you want to find ("capty"); it returns an object, so you need to cast/unbox it to the control type `Image`.  See below:

```
List<ImageGallery> _list = new List<ImageGallery>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count; i++) 
{
    Image image = (Image)ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("capty");
    ImageGallery ob = new ImageGallery(); 
    ob.ImageName = ""; 
    ob.Description = image.AlternateText; 
    _list.Add(ob); 
}
```

Comment: I am very amature. how to use find control.plz write complete expression.is any event argument needed?or which object is used for using FindControl?

Comment: @decoder see my update.  The argument is the `ID` of the control you're looking for, "capty".